# WPF: DataTrigger with multi properties condition

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, multibinding

So I have this `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFilesSelected}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EndAnimation"/>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="NewAnimation">
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"                                                                        
                                    From="0,50,0,0"                                                                         
                                    To="0,0,0,0"                                                                       
                                    DecelerationRatio=".9"                                                                   
                                    Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

And as you can see this `DataTrigger` is started when my `IsFilesSelected` property changes to `True` and I wonder how to assign another property and consider its value too when determine if I need to start my `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `MultiDataTrigger` with [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meet a set of conditions.

**Example lifted from the MSDN website**

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="Portland" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="OR" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

The above example will set the `Background` property when both the `Name` == "Portland" **AND** the `State` == "OR".